# How do I have an Apache site in a subdirectory, when the root is ProxyPassed to something else?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I have [shellinabox](http://code.google.com/p/shellinabox/) running on a subdomain through `HTTPS` and using `HTTP Basic Access Authentication` using the vhosts file below:

```
<VirtualHost xx.xx.xx.xx:80>
        ServerName              host.bananas.net
        Redirect                301 / https://host.bananas.net
        CustomLog               ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        ErrorLog                ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
</VirtualHost.net>

<VirtualHost xx.xx.xx.xx:443>
        ServerName              host.bananas.net
        SSLEngine               On
        SSLCertificateFile      /etc/apache2/ssl/bananas.net.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/apache2/ssl/bananas.net.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/sub.class1.server.ca.pem
        SSLCACertificateFile    /etc/apache2/ssl/ca.pem
        SetEnvIf                User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown
        ProxyRequests           Off
        ProxyPass               / http://localhost:4200/
        ProxyPassReverse        / http://localhost:4200/
        <Location />
                AuthUserFile    /etc/apache2/.htpasswd-secure
                AuthName        "Go Away!"
                AuthType        Basic
                Require         valid-user
                Order           Deny,Allow
                Allow           from all
        </Location>
        SetEnvIf                Request_URI "^/u" dontlog
        HostnameLookups         Double
        CustomLog               ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl_request.log "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
        ErrorLog                ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

I currently have another site on another subdomain, using this vhosts file:

```
<VirtualHost xx.xx.xx.xx:80>
        ServerName              files.bananas.net
        DocumentRoot            /var/www/files.bananas.net/

        CustomLog               ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        ErrorLog                ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

I would prefer to have the second site available at `https://host.bananas.net/files` instead of `http://files.bananas.net`.

The main reason for this is so that I can use the same SSL certificate, but there are other reasons as well.

How do I move the second site to be a subdirectory of the first site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exempt `/files` from the proxying:

```
ProxyPass /files !
```

Put it above the root's `ProxyPass`.  Looks like you'll also need to adjust your `DocumentRoot`s or file structure as needed to serve the content from the SSL vhost.

An example configuration:

```
<Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyRequests           Off
ProxyPreserveHost       On
<Location "/">
        ProxyPass               http://localhost:8080/
</Location>
<Location "/files">
        ProxyPass               !
</Location>
```

Comment: What should I make the `DocumentRoot`, now that the site within `/files/` is not at the root?  What needs to run is `https://bananas.net/files/index.php`.

Comment: If you want to keep the `files.bananas.net` host in place, then just point at that location in the directory structure; `Alias /files /var/www/files.bananas.net`.  Your authentication config from `<Location />` will still be applying, too; if that's not desired then undo that config in a `<Location /files>` block.

Comment: I have already moved the site's files to `/var/www/host.bananas.net/files/`, which I prefer.  How should I set a `DocumentRoot` for `https://bananas.net/files/index.php`?  Thanks.

Comment: `DocumentRoot /var/www/host.bananas.net` should do the trick.